# How to count how many times an IP packet with the same IP appears in pcap file then display items from the highest amount to the lowest in python

Tags: python

```
import socket
import dpkt


def print_pcap(pcap):
    """print source and destination IP addresses for all packets
    """
    for (unused_ts, buf) in pcap:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        ip = eth.data
        src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
        dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
       
        

def main():
    """test case"""
    pcap_file = "evidence-packet-analysis.pcap"
    with open(pcap_file, "rb") as file:
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(file)
        print(f"[*] analysing {pcap_file} for packets")
        print_pcap(pcap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your actual question? What is the code exactly supposed to do, what is it actually doing? Please read [ask].

Comment: Can you provide a short example of the pcap output?

Comment: So the code needs to read a pcap file and find all the IP address inside of it than count them and sort them @jps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scapy` to read the pcap file and get all the packets from the IP layer, then you can group then with itertools and order them. based on the length,

```py
from collections import Counter
from scapy.all import rdpcap, IP

ips = Counter([x.src for x in rdpcap('cap.pcap').getlayer(IP)])

for x in ips.most_common():
    print(x)
```